# what does it mean to say a space is norm separable?

Tags: analysis, terminology, definition, normed-spaces

I came across in my textbook the term: norm separable.  I looked in the textbook and online and could not find a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is that the topology generated by the norm is a separable topology. Namely there exists a countable set $\{v_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ such that for every $v$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n$ such that $\|v-v_n\|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the space is separable in the metric topology generated by the norm: it has a countable dense subset in that topology.